Array of a generic type
How do you do a simple array of generics in typescript:
interface IndexedType<T> {
    [id: string]: T
}

type indexedTypes = Array<IndexedType<T>>


do you mean how to make indexedTypes configurable with passing in a specific type? type indexedTypes<T> = Array<IndexedType<T>>?

@skyboyer - yeah that sounds right.

When we compose generics over generic we need specify a parameters and pass them to underlying generics:
interface IndexedType<T> {
    [id: string]: T
}

type indexedTypes<U> = Array<IndexedType<U>>

